# .htaccess on xampp 2 problems

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, http-status-code-404

The config.http file

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess code

```
# Handle directory access

# Custom 404 File not Found Page
ErrorDocument 404 /templates/replace404.php

# Prevent file listing from the unscruplous
IndexIgnore *

# Rewrite for process.php
#RewriteRule ^do/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) process.php?opt=$1 [NC, L]

# Rewrite for article
# RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/(09a-zA-Z_-)+) article.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC, L]
```

Okay first problem is it's not throwing the replace404.php page as expected, throws the standard 404 message ? The page exists etc so no idea why this is happening.

Second is the rewrite rule for process.php, if I un-comment that then it throws a 500 error when I try to access the site ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this part `ErrorDocument 404 /templates/replace404.php` you have to check your absolute path to the file.

And for 2nd part, first write `RewriteEngine On` before starting the rewrite conditions and rule,

```
RewriteRule ^do/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) process.php?opt=$1 [NC, L]
                                                      ^ this is the reason for 500
```

Use below instead

```
RewriteRule ^do/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) process.php?opt=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The 500 error fixed, yay, now behaving weird on replace404.php. It's being thrown but without the content, am getting an Error 404 system message?

Comment: Very most probably you have path mistake or error because your syntax is correct try to give it by full host name like `http://foo.example.com/templates/replace404.php`.